# Grails no id generated when saved and flushed

Tags: grails

Grails is not generating id for database object. I created object with corresponding domain class. Now if I call save(flush:true) i get null id in ...

But shouldnt the flush generate the id ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it has really saved it, this typically means there were errors so you need to capture it and relay it back or whatever.
you should be able to see the errors by doing

```
if (!object. save(flush:true)) {
  // throw new RuntimeException("something went wrong");
   //println "object errors ${object.errors} //.allErrors}
   //or 
   //object.errors.reject('object.failed.saved', '')
}
```

Sometimes it is even more nested failure and can be caught like this

```
try {
            subobject.removeFromElements(object)
            subobject.save(flush:true)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ValidationException('failed.message',subobject.errors)
        }
```

If you try first method first to see if errors the finally if still nothing try as a test by wrapping a try catch around entire save block to see if other components are causing your issue. Between that lies you answer

Comment: After few hours of snooping around in the code, i think we have found the cause of this error. In beforeEvent we are asking getDirtyPropertyNames() and this is somehow causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding following in the mapping?

static mapping = {

```
    id(generator: "assigned")

}
```

Comment: Yes this is present. Everything was working fine. And then when i split a large method into pieces. Nothing worked anymore. Every single type os saving that worked before is not working now. Seems like some larger error.