# Update on 2 or more tables

Tags: postgresql, grails, gsp

I have a problem with the following piece of code, actually I have the following method:

```
@Transactional
def update(Subsidiary subsidiary,User user) {
    if (subsidiary == null) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (subsidiary.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond subsidiary.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }
    user.save flush:true
    user.addToSubsidiaries(subsidiary)
    user.save flush:true
    subsidiary.addToPhones(phone)
    subsidiary.save flush:true



    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'subsidiary.label', default: 'Subsidiary'), subsidiary.id])
            redirect subsidiary
        }
        '*'{ respond subsidiary, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

Actually from the view in gsp

```
      <g:form resource="${this.subsidiary}"  class="form-horizontal" method="PUT">
       <f:input bean="user"  class="form-control"  property="name"/>
       <f:input bean="subsidiary"  class="form-control"  property="dob"/>
       </g:form>
```

and these is the way I send the info the method unfortunately it loads everything properly but I get no changes the update does not work, the database is postgres and I already did a method similar but it only update one table and I also used the same sentences to create one subsidiary with success, however in the part of update it does not work it does nothing, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did phone come from? Outside of the method? Can you try user.save( flush: true, failOnError: true )

Comment: phone is just another domain but for obvious reasons I wont post the edit.gsp since it is very large.. but on domain the phone is as nullable so there is no problem.

Comment: You have the statement `subsidiary.addToPhones(phone)` but where is the phone variable coming from?

Comment: as I said the gsp is very very long, but if you really need it...
is like this

Comment: <f:input bean="phone"   class="hidden"  property="phone"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217448/grails-no-id-generated-when-saved-and-flushed/41219745#41219745. I think you have a lot missing in that code to give any clear answers for a start your update is user.addToSubsidiaries(subsidiary) on each attempt then subsidiary.addToPhones(phone) - does it ever need to check if it exists first ?